# A better way to say "encompass beyond" to go beyond the frontier of technology

Tags: ellipsis

I am trying to rewrite the following sentence that I wrote

> Meet the newest pattern-recognition technology, with predefined sets
>   assorted to encompass outliers.

in this way :

> Meet the newest technology, with predefined sets
>   assorted to encompass beyond.

I am rewriting the sentence because I cannot use the phrase "the newest pattern-recognition technology" for a reason. But as soon as I replace it with "the newest technology", I find the sentence to be a little ambiguous without the reason to "encompass outliers." So I decided to make the sentence more general and encompass not "outliers" but "beyond the newest technology".

First, I would like to know if the constructions of two sentences are acceptable in the first place.

Second, I would like to know if the second sentence does convey the meaning that the "predefined sets" are available to accomodate what is not possible with current technology.

Third, I would like to know if there is a better way to say "encompass beyond" to *go beyond the frontier of technology*.

Comment: What are you trying to say when you write _"assorted to"_? That is not a meaningful phrase in English. What dictionary did you use to learn about the adjective "assorted"? Unfortunately, as written, _"assorted to encompass beyond"_ doesn't convey anything.

Comment: I actually learned it from "assorted chocolate". I used it in the sense that the predefined sets are cherry-picked and arranged to accommodate eccentric demands.

Comment: What _dictionary_ (not which phrase) did you use to learn about the adjective "assorted"? It does not mean what you think it does, and it never takes the preposition _to._ [**Here**](http://onelook.com) is a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I actually used "to" in order to construct an infinitive verb with "encompass". If this is not the proper way of conveying my intention, would you kindly suggest an alternative expression to use in the context?

Comment: Again: what dictionary do you use? Do you know what a _preposition_ is? Do you know what _every_ preposition needs? What kind of word do you think _beyond_ is? Without a dictionary, you might as well be trying to make up your own language! I don't mean to sound less than gracious, but our mission at ELL is to help you learn English—not to rewrite copy.

Comment: Well, I am not using a dictionary right now. I am constructing a sentence based on what I have heard. I understand that phrasal verbs needs object. But at the same time, I remember the phrase such as "to infinity and beyond" which is used without preposition. I used the word "beyond" not as a preposition following a verb but as a noun.

Comment: In "to infinity and beyond", beyond _is_ a preposition.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I wanted to use "beyond" in that sense like in the expression "to infinity and beyond".

Comment: @narusawa I understand the general meaning of your first sentence but not your second.  It sounds like you're trying to say "meet the latest technology (designed) to go beyond ... the latest technology?"  That's called a [tautology](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tautology).  You need to say more.  Also it's not clear what you mean by "assorted".  [Assorted](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/assorted) is normally an adjective and not a verb as you've used it here.

Comment: @narusawa I do like your phrase "predefined sets are available to accommodate what is not possible with the current technology" although again this field is not familiar enough for me to know what a "predefined set" means in this context.

Comment: @Andrew _Assorted_ is not "normally an adjective" any more than _stupid_ is "normally an adjective". It's just a common or garden variety adjective. We can't _stupid_ sets  any more than we can _assort_ sets.